# Из-за этих пестрых обоев(,) традиционно(,) ничего не видно

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Нужны запятые здесь?

> Из-за этих пестрых обоев(,) традиционно(,) ничего не видно.

Может ли *традиционно*, в значении *как обычно*, будучи использованным, быть вводным, обособляясь, словом? Или так нельзя?

А так?

> Из-за этих пестрых обоев(,) по традиции(,) ничего не видно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну какая может быть традиция (традиционно) в смотрении чрез пёстрые обои? Не просвечивают ли стены?

Если не считаться с тем, что предложение самопально-искусственное, то запятые не нужны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это вообще про другое) Есть такая игра, где все проходит на фоне обоев) Когда пестрые, саму игру сложнее увидеть)

Comment: Что значит "самопально-искусственный"? И ставятся ли в итоге, если у слова такое значение?

Comment: Максик, поняла. Самопальную искусственность отменяем. Но я же и пишу: ***Если не считаться с тем, что предложение самопально-искусственное, то запятые не нужны.*** Это подтверждает картинка из справочника по пунктуации. От слова "традиционно" откажись, замени на "как всегда", в запятых: https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0&mode=all

Comment: В общем, запятые ставить? Я не понимаю значение слова "самопально-искусственный"..

Comment: САМОПАЛ, -а; м. Разг.-сниж. О том, что изготовлено кустарным образом (с имитацией фирменной продукции). *Джинсы импортные? - Нет, с.* ИСКУССТВЕННЫЙ.  Сделанный наподобие настоящего, природного, а ткж. сделанный для замены, имитации настоящего, природного.

Comment: Убираем традицию, обособляем  "как всегда".

Comment: То есть обособиться может только "как всегда", но "традиционно" вообще нельзя обособлять?

Comment: @Максим, а можно философский вопрос по теме. Как вы думаете, может, мы на жизнь всегда смотрим через пестрые обои и поэтому плохо понимаем происходящее? Ваша игра не может помочь в этом разобраться?

Comment: @Максим Обособить должно "как всегда", но "традиционно" вообще нельзя обособлять.